# Projeto git com duas pastas separadas

Tags: git, bitbucket

Ola,

hoje tenho um projeto web. Os dados publicos dentro da pasta "public_html/":

```
public_html/projeto-publico/
```

e outra pasta com os arquivos sensiveis ("projeto-backend") esta fora da "public_html/":

```
projeto-backend/public_html/...
```

Basicamente uma pasta tem os arquivos .php e a pasta publica os .js e .css. Ambas são do mesmo projeto. Gostaria de saber como, organizo isso no git? Visto que são pastas diferentes. Eu teria que ter 2 repositórios separados para cada pasta no git?

Obrigado!

Comment: olá Thiago, até onde eu conheço as permissões são por repositório, logo se quer ter acessos diferentes para cada um vai precisar ter repositórios diferentes

Comment: Foi o que pensei também, mas como sou novo no git pensei que ele poderia ter uma alternativa a isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente a sua pergunta, mas, se entendi, você quer saber se precisa ter repositórios separados, visto que possui stacks diferentes no projeto.

O ponto é: você precisa utilizar esse repositório para deploy dessa aplicação em algum lugar (uma integração com plataformas de hospedagem de aplicações)?

O objetivo é somente armanezar seus projetos e versionar seu código pra si mesmo?

**O repositório será integrado para deploy**

Nesse caso, é importante que todos os arquivos do código (se for um framework, por ex) sejam subidos para o repositório. Claro que arquivos mais sensíveis, como chaves de api, secrets keys e etc, **JAMAIS** devem ser subidos pro git.

**O repositório não fará integração para deploy**

Nesse caso, você pode subir somente as pastas que deseja (no caso, a pasta *public_html*). Explico como fazer isso no final dessa resposta.

**Caso comum de monolito (como parece ser o seu)**
Em casos em que vc tem as duas stacks, front e back, na mesma pasta, e projeto, você pode manter os dois da mesma forma no repositório, sem problema nenhum.

A questão aí é só o quão "secretos" são seus arquivos e o quão vc quer manter isso privado (nesse caso, seria ideal manter o próprio repo privado então). Mas, não sendo, pode subir as duas pastas normalmente no repositório, não esquecendo de ignorar arquivos de chaves, e segredos que geralmente vão via código (prefira sempre variáveis de ambiente pra esses casos).

**Ignorando pastas e arquivos no git**

Ignorando pastas

- Crie ou edite o arquivo .gitignore dentro do repositório
- Insira a pasta que deseja ignorar no repo

  projeto-backend/public_html

Ignorando arquivos específicos

```
projeto-backend/public_html/id_key.pem

projeto-backend/public_html/sensible-file.php
```

O comum nesse caso, pelo que sei, é:

- coloca as duas pastas de stacks no mesmo repo
- ignora arquivos sensíveis, como chaves e etc

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Certo, acredito que existam várias respostas possíveis para esta questão, vou levantar duas possibilidades e abordagens.

### Repositórios Separados

Uma opção seria ter duas aplicações, uma de front-end e outra de back, neste cenário o ideal seria ter um front bem desacoplado do backend, onde a comunicação ocorra por meio de http ou sockets.

Neste cenário você teria:

- Um repo para a aplicação web frontend (HTML, CSS, JS (Podendo ou não usar algo como angular, react, etc)).
- Um ou mais repos para as aplicações backend

A comunicação ocorre por meio de uma ou mais APIs no backend consumidas pelo front-end.

### Monolito

Observando a sua pergunta é bem possível que você já tenha um monolito, **neste caso não é necessário quebrar ele em múltiplos repositórios**.

É possível manter este monolito unido e ainda assim fazer o deploy da forma desejada.

Em alguns frameworks como o Laravel no PHP, Rails no Ruby existem diretórios para os arquivos estáticos e o front controller que processa as requisições.

Nestes casos é possível fazer o deploy de sua aplicação fora do diretório do seu servidor web (apache, nginx, etc) e adicionar no seu servidor web um link simbolico.

Sistemas operacionais UNIX e Windows possuem este recurso, onde você pode criar um "atalho" para uma pasta dentro de outra pasta, onde para todos os efeitos este atalho é tratado pelas aplicações (ex. Servidor Web) como sendo a pasta, neste caso assumindo que você tivesse um servidor apache no linux você poderia fazer algo assim:

- `/var/www/aplicacao/` - Diretório de deploy de sua aplicacao.
- `/var/www/aplicacao/public/` - Diretório com assets e o front controller
- `/var/www/public_html/` - Diretório Web do apache
- `/var/www/public_html/aplicacao/` - Link simbolico para /var/www/aplicacao/public/

Alterando as configurações do apache para servir o diretório `/var/www/public_html/aplicacao/` em um determinado domínio e ajustando as configurações de acesso você não precisaria se preocupar de alguém conseguir acessar arquivos fora do diretório `/var/www/aplicacao/public/` ao acessar seu domínio.

Comment: Então as duas pastas ficariam no mesmo repositorio ? E como ficaria na hora de fazer deploy no servidor para que cada pasta va para o devido lugar?

Comment: Olá Thiago, neste caso você não separaria as pastas. Ao invés de separar você faz depot onde o servidor não pode servir elas. Aí você cria dentro da pasta do servidor um link simbólico para a pasta pública (com o índex.php e os assets) para que essa é somente está pasta possa ser servida.